# How to handle 2 phone permissions for getting IMEI number and mobile number of the device in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

In my application I am getting my phone number through **mobile number: ^1.0.4** library and also I am getting IMEI number through **device information: ^0.0.4.** For getting both I need to use the handle 2 permissions for phone but it shows only read phone contacts but **not showing read phone status and identity** in my app permissions. So anyone please guide me how to do it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the device information permission to android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml and android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml files after the close tag of manifest. You can see it in the debug's manifest file.
Add this:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`
The mobile number package has a permission request method as you can see it  [in the API reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/mobile_number/latest/)

Comment: I already added this permission in android manifest.